# Is it possible to call a Postgres SQL script with '\i' but referencing the file as a string variable?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to invoke a SQL script within another SQL script using `pgsql`.

I already saw that I can use

```
\i 'path/to/file.sql'
```

where `path/to/files.sql` is between single quotes.

I was trying to replace `'path/to/file.sql'` with a variable instead, like

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    ls_id INT := 271195;
    tokens VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
    tokens := CONCAT(ls_id, '_tokens.sql');
    \i tokens
END $$;
```

Is this possible some way or another?

Comment: You cannot to use `\i` inside `DO` statement. `\i` is `psql` statement (client side). `DO` is SQL statement (server side). Both sides can be on different computers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not something you can do directly in sql because `\i` is a psql command and not actually SQL at all.

But the following should demonstrate how you can go about it.

```
SELECT ('something' || '_and_' || 'something_else.sql') as filename \gset


\i :filename
```

The `gset` will create a psql variable for you based on the result of the query. Again the `\gset` is actually just for psql rather than being sent to the backend.

Then you can reference the psql variable prefixed by a colon.

Note that this is just a macro-style text substitution. You will need to deal with quoting spaces and backslashes and so on yourself.

Comment: Your solution works outside the `DO` block, but It's important to call the file inside the `DO` block. As @Pavel Stehule said, it seems it's not possible to use `\i` as `\gset` inside a `DO`block.

Comment: The SQL isn't executing on the client machine, so probably wouldn't be able to access the file anyway.